# how can i use Rspec Expectations in page object classes

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, page-object-gem, rspec-expectations

How can i use Rspec Expectations in Page-object classes. I need to assert elements. Currently i am using xpath, other locators to check element existence. I know using it is step definitions. But i need it in classes.

### Code:

```
class AssertTest
include PageObject

span(:success, text: "Message added successfully")

def assert_element
    success_element.when_present (or) success?
    # I need to use Rspec expectations instead

    # continue...
end
end
```

In step definitions i am able to use it like:

```
@current_page.text.should include "message"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have already required 'rspec', you just need to include the RSpec::Matchers module in your class.

```
class AssertTest
  include PageObject
  include RSpec::Matchers

  span(:success, text: "Message added successfully")

  def assert_element()
    # Example assertions for checking element is present
    success_element.should be_visible
    expect(success_element).to be_visible
  end

end
```

Note that some would recommend only doing assertions in tests (not in page objects).

Comment: Definitely want to second Justin's caution regarding putting assertions into your page classes!